# Guarantee that getchar receives newline or EOF (eventually)?

Tags: c, newline, stdin, eof, getchar

I would like to read characters from `stdin` until one of the following occurs:

- an end-of-line marker is encountered (the normal case, in my thinking),
- the `EOF` condition occurs, or
- an error occurs.

How can I guarantee that one of the above events will happen eventually? In other words, how do I guarantee that `getchar` will eventually return either `\n` or `EOF`, provided that no error (in terms of `ferror(stdin)`) occurs?

```
// (How) can we guarantee that the LABEL'ed statement will be reached?
int done = 0;
while (!0) if (
        (c = getchar()) == EOF || ferror(stdin) || c == '\n') break;
LABEL: done = !0;
```

If `stdin` is connected to a device that *always* delivers some character *other than* `'\n'`, none of the above conditions will occur. It seems like the answer will have to do with the properties of the device. Where can those details be found (in the doumentation for compiler, device firmware, or device hardware perhaps)?

In particular, I am interested to know if keyboard input is guaranteed to be terminated by an end-of-line marker or end-of-file condition. Similarly for files stored on disc / SSD.

Typical use case: user enters text on the keyboard. Program reads first few characters and discards all remaining characters, up to the end-of-line marker or end-of-file (because some buffer is full or after that everything is comments, etc.).

I am using **C89**, but I am curious if the answer depends on which C standard is used.

Comment: Because standard input comes from an external source (User, other program, etc.) it's hard to be 100% sure that you'll get either a newline or EOF from a malicious user. `while true; do printf x; done | ./yourprogram` for example will just give it an unending stream of x's.

Comment: As I suspected, @Shawn, this question goes beyond C. I suppose in practice, programs needing to approximate the desired effect use some sort of wrapper around `stdin` that e.g., quits after so many reads.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Let's say I run your program, then I put a weight on my keyboard's "X" key and go on vacation to Hawaii. On the way there, I get struck by lightning and die.

There will never be any input other than 'x'.

Or, I may decide to type the complete story of Moby Dick, without pressing enter. It will probably take a few days. How long should your program wait before it decides that maybe I won't ever finish typing?

What do you ***want*** it to do?

Comment: Looks like the obvious compromise is to put a limit on the number of sequential non-`\n`'s returned. Any other obvious compromises?

Comment: @AnaNimbus What do you ***want*** your program to do, if I put a weight on my "X" key and go on vacation?

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that a general solution is not possible, so I need to think of each application. In your example, I would like to require the _keyboard_ (or keyboard device driver) to set the read error flag if such an event occurs. I know---then we have to define "such an event"---maybe `keydown time > vacation duration`. Maybe this is turning into a user interface question---about what "typical users" expect (or will tolerate). This StackOverflow input field will accept only so many characters. A limited character count seems to be the thing most users are expected to tolerate.

Comment: @AnaNimbus Yes, it's a question about what you want your user interface to do. I think the most sensible thing is for the computer to do exactly what you tell it. If the computer is ignoring what you type, and you continue typing, the computer will keep ignoring it, rather than popping up a message saying "Hey! I've ignored a lot of text! Are you sure you didn't mean to hit enter?" Something like the latter may be appropriate for something aimed at kids, or adults inexperienced with computers, but I wouldn't expect it.

Comment: @AnaNimbus or I decide to type in a long story (without pressing enter). What should your program do if I type in a long story without pressing enter?

Comment: @AnaNimbus "*I guess what you're saying is that a general solution is not possible*" I think issue is that you haven't defined what the problem is. The answer to your question "How can I guarantee that one of the above events will happen eventually?" is "You can't". You're trying to figure out what to do given that the guarantee you asked about is not possible -- and there are perhaps infinitely many possible answers to that. What are your requirements?

Comment: Right. How do I guarantee that the user will not go to Hawaii? You can't. Do something else.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at all the discussion in the comments, it seems you are looking in the wrong place:

It is not a matter of keyboard drivers or wrapping `stdin`.

It is also not a matter of what programming language you are using.

It is a matter of the purpose of the input in your software.
Basically, it is up to you as a programmer to know how much input you want or need, and then decide when to stop reading input, even if valid input is still available.

Note, that not only are there devices that can send input forever without triggering EOF or end of line condition, but there are also programs that will happily read input forever.

This is by design.

Common examples can be found in POSIX style OS (like Linux) command line tools.
Here is a simple example:

```
cat /dev/urandom | hexdump
```

This will print random numbers for as long as your computer is running, or until you hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

Though `cat` will stop working when there is nothing more to print (EOF or any read error), it does not expect such an end, so unless there is a bug in the implementation you are using it should happily run forever.

So the real question is:
When does your program need to stop reading characters and why?

Answer (score 1):

> If stdin is connected to a device that always delivers some character other than '\n', none of the above conditions will occur.

A device such as `/dev/zero`, for example.  Yes, stdin can be connected to a device that never provides a newline or reaches EOF, and that is not expected ever to report an error condition.

> It seems like the answer will have to do with the properties of the device.

Indeed so.

> Where can those details be found (in the doumentation for compiler, device firmware, or device hardware perhaps)?

Generally, it's a question of the device *driver*.  And in some cases (such as the `/dev/zero` example) that's all there is anyway.  Generally drivers do things that are sensible for the underlying hardware, but in principle, they don't have to do.

> In particular, I am interested to know if keyboard input is guaranteed to be terminated by an end-of-line marker or end-of-file condition.

No.  Generally speaking, an end-of-line marker is sent by a terminal device if and only if the <enter> key is pressed.  An end-of-file condition might be signaled if the terminal disconnects (but the program continues), or if the user explicitly causes one to be sent (by typing <-<D> on Linux or Mac, for example, or <-<Z> on Windows).  Neither of those events need actually happen on any given run of a program, and it is very common for the latter not to do.

> Similarly for files stored on disc / SSD.

You can generally rely on data read from an ordinary file to contain newlines where they are present in the file itself.  If the file is open in text mode, then the system-specific text line terminator will also be translated to a newline, if it differs.  It is not necessary for a file to contain any of those, so a program reading from a regular file might never see a newline.

You can rely on EOF being signaled when a read is attempted while the file position is at or past the and of the file's data.

> Typical use case: user enters text on the keyboard. Program reads first few characters and discards all remaining characters, up to the end-of-line marker or end-of-file (because some buffer is full or after that everything is comments, etc.).

I think you're trying too hard.

Reading to end-of-line might be a reasonable thing to do in some cases.  Expecting a newline to eventually be reached is reasonable if the program is intended to support interactive use.  But trying to ensure that invalid data cannot be fed to your program is a losing cause.  Your objective should be to accept the widest array of inputs you reasonably can, and to fail gracefully when other inputs are presented.

If you *need* to read input in a line-by-line mode then by all means do that, and document that you do it.  If only the first *n* characters of each line are significant to the program then document that, too.  Then, if your program never terminates when a user connects its input to `/dev/zero` that's on them, not on you.

On the other hand, try to avoid placing arbitrary constraints, especially on sizes of things.  If there is not a natural limit on the size of something, then no artificial limit you introduce will ever be enough.

Comment: +1. A lot of good things to think about. Available memory or available storage (maybe available time?) seems to be a reasonable definition for "natural limit" in many practical cases. E.g., "... 'grep'... has _no limits_ on input line length _other than available memory_" (GNU [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) 3.0 info page, emphasis added).

Comment: @AnaNimbus, what I had in mind for natural limits was more along the lines of externally-specified formats with which your program must comply.  The difference between these and system resource limits is that the former is a fixed limit that you can know and program for up front, whereas with the latter, you usually don't know the limit in advance but instead just use as much as you need until the system won't (or can't) give you any more.  Good discipline with handling the return values of your function calls will generally provide for graceful failure if the latter run out.

Comment: @AnaNimbus note that memory will only be a limiting factor if you intend to store the input. If you only process it and then discard, like for example in a hashing algorithm, then memory is not a constraint.